# How can you prevent fake events in firebase analytics

Tags: firebase, logging, google-analytics, analytics

I've recently set up Firebase Analytics with my website. I was beginning to add some events to be logged and realized any arbitrary event could artificially be called. I could just go into my browser's console and run the command `firebase.analytics().logEvent('some_fake_event')`.

If you know a website is using firebase analytics, what's to stop you from simply spamming fake events into your console? The website owner's analytics would become fairly screwed up. Also, firebase mentions that there's a 500 event-type limit. One could also run `firebase.analytics().logEvent('fake_event_1')`, `firebase.analytics().logEvent('fake_event_2')`, etc. Oops, the website owner can't create any more new (legitimate) event types.

What is in place to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

The `logEvent` method will be available once you rely on standard firebase SDK. The only way to prevent this would be to obfuscate the library you're using.

Comment: Surprised this is not seen as a larger flaw of firebase analytics. Seems like a big deal to me. I did end up obfuscating on my website by using the firebase npm package with webpack. This also makes the `firebase` object not directly accessible from the browser console.